# How do I properly strongly-type a reactive array whose elements are interfaced Class objects?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to create a reactive array that can hold data that I am getting from a database via a HTTP request using a SQL query. I do not have access to this database, and my only method of retrieving data is by submitting a query. The request will store the retrieved data into a reactive state that I created. Therefore, my code looks like this:

```
const state: any = reactive({
  posts: [],
});

function getPosts(query: string) {
  query = `SELECT * FROM dept_sales WHERE store_id = 1 AND date = 20181114`;
  axios
    .post(`url_link`, query)
    .then((response) => {
      state.posts = response.data;
    })
}
```

Now, I want to practice better Typescript, so I am trying to add typing so that I do not rely on using the type 'any'. I know that the data I retrieve here will be in the following format, so I created this interface and class:

```
interface ISalesData {
  storeId: number;
  salesAmount: number;
  salesQuantity: number;
  salesDepartment: number;
}

class SalesData implements ISalesData {
  storeId: number;
  salesAmount?: number;
  salesQuantity?: number;
  salesDepartment?: number;

  constructor(
    storeId: number,
    salesAmount: number,
    salesQuantity: number,
    salesDepartment: number
  ) {
    this.storeId = storeId;
    this.salesAmount = salesAmount;
    this.salesQuantity = salesQuantity;
    this.salesDepartment = salesDepartment;
  }
}
```

I am trying to loop through the data in state.posts, and with each loop, create a new SalesData object and adding it to a new typed array.

```
let salesContainer = reactive({}); // this works, but it still has type: any

let salesContainer: Array<SalesData> = []; // this compiles, 
//and properly types each property, 
//but because it is not reactive, nothing renders properly on screen.


function typeSalesData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < state.posts.length; i++) {
    salesContainer[i] = new SalesData(
      state.posts[i].ds_store_id,
      state.posts[i].ds_amt,
      state.posts[i].ds_qty,
      state.posts[i].ds_dept
    );
```

How do I create an array that is typed (an array that holds objects of type SalesData) that is also reactive?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to use the following code to create a reactive array with interfaced objects:

```
let salesContainer = reactive({
      sales: [] as SalesData[],
});
```

However, now, in order to access the data, I'd need to use:

```
salesContainer.sales[0].
```

I was trying to come up with a solution where I could simply do :

```
salesContainer[0];
```

Is there a better solution than what I have?

EDIT with better(?) solution:

```
let salesContainer: SalesData[] = reactive([]);

function buildSalesData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < state.posts.length; i++) {
    salesContainer.push(
      new SalesData(
        state.posts[i].ds_store_id,
        state.posts[i].ds_amt,
        state.posts[i].ds_qty,
        state.posts[i].ds_dept
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine!

Comment: Just pass an array? `reactive([])`

Comment: Do you mean like `let salesContainer = reactive([]);` ? Because this results in a salesContainer with no strong typing

Comment: How? Pass a generic parameter: `reactive<SalesData[]>([])`